# How to block direct access to thank you page on NextJS?

Tags: next.js, routes

I have a `thank-you.tsx` page under the pages folder, and I'm looking for a way to **prevent users from accessing it directly**.

In other words, they should only be able to view this page if they have successfully submitted a form.

What is the most efficient way to implement it using nextjs?